# if $f\in \mathcal{C}^1 (\mathbb{R})$ and $f,f'$ are integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ converges to $0$ in $± \infty$.

Tags: limits, functions

We consider an element $f$ of $\mathcal{C}^1 (\mathbb{R})$; we suppose that $f$ and $f'$ are integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$  converges to $0$ in $± \infty$.

My effort:

for $x>y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\int_{y}^{x}{f'(t)dt}|$$

$f'$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists $c>0$ such that :

For  $~x>~y>c~~$ : $|\int_{y}^{x}{f'(t)dt}|<1$

For  $~y<x<-c$ : $|\int_{y}^{x}{f'(t)dt}|<1$

then there is $M>0$ such that $ |f(x)|<M$ for $|x|>c$. Can this give the desired result? if not, please an idea.

Comment: Use integrability of $f'$ to conclude that $f$ has _a_ limit at $\pm \infty$. Then use integrability of $f$ to conclude that this limit must be $0$.